# Rendering Exception on iOS using Gluon/JavaFXPorts

Tags: ios, javafxports, gluon, gluon-mobile

After trying out some apps on iOS with Gluon I noticed some rendering bugs.
Firstly the JavaFX `LineChart` behaves incorrectly. The lines are displaced and the shadows don't show up correctly. I didn't examine this further but this might be related to the following problem.

The more important thing is that there is an exception while rendering the Gluon demo App called `DoodleTrace`. After painting the line (about 20cm long on the iPad) I get an exception in the rendering Thread:
(Note: iPad 3 running iOS 7)

Triggered once (after about 20 cm):

```
va.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Upload requires 1793077 elements, but only 1102848 elements remain in the buffer  
    at com.sun.prism.impl.BaseTexture.checkUpdateParams(BaseTexture.java)  
    at com.sun.prism.es2.ES2Texture.update(ES2Texture.java)  
    at com.sun.prism.impl.BaseContext.flushVertexBuffer(BaseContext.java)  
    at com.sun.prism.impl.ps.BaseShaderContext.setRenderTarget(BaseShaderContext.java)  
    at com.sun.prism.impl.BaseContext.setRenderTarget(BaseContext.java)  
    at com.sun.prism.impl.BaseGraphics.<init>(BaseGraphics.java)  
    at com.sun.prism.impl.ps.BaseShaderGraphics.<init>(BaseShaderGraphics.java)  
    at com.sun.prism.es2.ES2Graphics.<init>(ES2Graphics.java)  
    at com.sun.prism.es2.ES2Graphics.create(ES2Graphics.java)  
    at com.sun.prism.es2.ES2SwapChain.prepare(ES2SwapChain.java)  
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.PresentingPainter.run(PresentingPainter.java)  
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java)  
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java)  
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.RenderJob.run(RenderJob.java)  
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java)  
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java)  
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumRenderer$PipelineRunnable.run(QuantumRenderer.java)  
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java)  
Outstanding resource locks detected:  
ES2 Vram Pool: 3,457,040 used (0.6%), 91,324,416 target (17.0%), 536,870,912 max  
7 total resources being managed  
average resource age is 28.4 frames  
0 resources at maximum supported age (0.0%)  
3 resources marked permanent (42.9%)  
1 resources have had mismatched locks (14.3%)  
1 resources locked (14.3%)  
6 resources contain interesting data (85.7%)  
0 resources disappeared (0.0%)
```

Triggered on every touch event after the above exception occurred:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Upload requires 1793077 elements, but only 1102848 elements remain in the buffer  
    at com.sun.prism.impl.BaseTexture.checkUpdateParams(BaseTexture.java)  
    at com.sun.prism.es2.ES2Texture.update(ES2Texture.java)  
    at com.sun.prism.impl.BaseContext.flushVertexBuffer(BaseContext.java)  
    at com.sun.prism.impl.ps.BaseShaderContext.setRenderTarget(BaseShaderContext.java)  
    at com.sun.prism.impl.BaseContext.setRenderTarget(BaseContext.java)  
    at com.sun.prism.impl.BaseGraphics.<init>(BaseGraphics.java)  
    at com.sun.prism.impl.ps.BaseShaderGraphics.<init>(BaseShaderGraphics.java)  
    at com.sun.prism.es2.ES2Graphics.<init>(ES2Graphics.java)  
    at com.sun.prism.es2.ES2Graphics.create(ES2Graphics.java)  
    at com.sun.prism.es2.ES2SwapChain.createGraphics(ES2SwapChain.java)  
    at com.sun.prism.es2.ES2SwapChain.createGraphics(ES2SwapChain.java)  
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.PresentingPainter.run(PresentingPainter.java)  
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java)  
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java)  
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.RenderJob.run(RenderJob.java)  
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java)  
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java)  
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumRenderer$PipelineRunnable.run(QuantumRenderer.java)  
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java)
```

Comment: DoodleTrace sample uses the plugin with version 1.0.7, please update to 1.0.8 and try again, the error you have posted has been already fixed.

Comment: The [sample script](https://bitbucket.org/gluon-oss/samples/src/master/DoodleTrace/) has been already updated.

Comment: Thank you! You did a great job! The exception is gone and the app doesn't freeze any more. But it still becomes incredible slow after drawing a long line...